# Installing scipy on CentOS 6 (OpenBLAS problem)

Tags: scipy, centos6, blas, openblas

I'm trying to install scipy on CentOS 6 with python 3.9.18 and get error:

```
../scipy/meson.build:159:9: ERROR: Dependency "OpenBLAS" not found, tried pkgconfig
```

The problem is that CentOS 6 doesn't provide `yum install openblas-devel` but there is `blas-devel`.

I though I could use `blas-devel` instead and from [the scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/building/blas_lapack.html) I tried:

```
./python -m pip install scipy -Csetup-args=-Dblas=blas -Csetup-args=-Dlapack=lapack
```

but this didn't work.

What would the desired way of installing scipy in my case?
Should I try to build OpenBLAS and LAPACK from sources?

Comment: The easiest way to install scipy would be to use a pre-built binary using pip.

Comment: It requires OpenBLAS.  CentOS 6 doesn't have it

Comment: The OpenBLAS  library is contained in the wheel.

Comment: Yes but when I type `pip install scipy` on CentOS 6 in tries to build it from source. Probably wheels are built on CentOS 7...

Comment: I think Centos6 is pretty old! The recommended instructions are at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/building/index.html and with the instructions you linked to for choosing a BLAS implementation. When you say that the build didn't work, what where the error message? Failing that you could try building OpenBLAS yourself, it's not too difficult.

Comment: There's also a new option that you could try:
```
pip install scipy-openblas32
python dev.py build --with-scipy-openblas 
```

Comment: Yes I have successfully built OpenBLAS but I couldn't point where it is to scipy: scipy could not find it. I ended up installing it with something like `python -m pip install scipy --prefer-binary` and that seems to me worked.

Thank you for the `pip install scipy-openblas32 python dev.py build --with-scipy-openblas` I hope this will work as well because as I just revealed my `pip` knowledge are pretty poor.